# Django - Trying to keep track of user's cart

Tags: django

I have a cart where I have two fields that I use to connect to a user. One is `User`, I use that if user is logged in. Other is `session`, this is used to keep track of logged out users. It uses `session_key`.

Now the problem I am facing is that when a user logs in the cart disconnects because the `session_key` has changed. I know that I can use cookie to identify the browser or client. But I am not able to find an example of Django's `set_cookies` being used with JsonResponse(AJAX call). It is only for HttpResponse.

I think I could use either of these two ways, if possible.

1. Set cookie through AJAX
2. Or Set cookie when user visits website. I want this with ability that no matter which page the user visits at fist the cookie should be set on that visit.

Does anyone have a resource or example to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case this might help someone.

I went with the point# 2 mentioned in my question. What I needed was `Middleware`. They allow us to inject data in `request` and `response` objects for our views.

In `myproject/cart/middleware.py` I have this:

```
from . import settings as cart_settings

import uuid

class SetCartSessionKeyMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        cart_key = request.COOKIES.get(cart_settings.CART_SESSION_ID_KEY, None)

        if cart_key:
            response = self.get_response(request)
        else:
            cart_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            response = self.get_response(request)
            response.set_cookie(cart_settings.CART_SESSION_ID_KEY, cart_id)

        return response
```

In my `settings.py` I have:

```
CART_SESSION_ID_KEY = 'user_cart_id'
```

Now you can access that cookie anywhere where you have access to `request` object like in your views. You can do `session_id = request.COOKIES.get(cart_settings.CART_SESSION_ID_KEY, None)`

Don't forget to import settings in views as you did in the `middleware.py` file. Remember that it is my app settings.py(ie. `myproject/cart/settings.py`) not the main project settings.py.

In your `myproject/settings.py` register your new middleware like this

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
     ....

    ## Our custom middlewares
    'cart.middleware.SetCartSessionKeyMiddleware',
]
```

Enjoy!